# Is there way to forward the request in the Http handler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing http handler.I just want to add some http headers, after that, I would like the behavior is the same as before.

I am processing like the following

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
 {
    HttpResponse Response = context.Response;     

    Response.Headers.Add("item", "data");
 }
```

But it does not function the same as before. What I missed here?

Comment: I think you need to expand your question - why would you need a handler just to add headers? There are multiple/easier ways to do that depending on what your intended result is...

Comment: @EdSF, Please let me other ways. I am not restricting to handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can use an action filter to add custom headers to a response. Like this:

```
public class HttpHeaderAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public HttpHeaderAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader(Name, Value);
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can I use this MVC as a seperate handler in IIS?